# A freelancer billed me, we had no contract and what he provided was not useable. What should I do?

Tags: professionalism, freelancing, employment-agreement

I met with a freelance copywriter to discuss a project on which I am the Creative Director. He emailed me 'some' copy which was not useable at all. He even altered GM tagline from 'Quality is Job One', to 'Safety is Job One'. Not at all original work.
I wrote the copy myself for the project and contacted him relaying thank you but I would not be needing his services. He sent me a bill for $350 hours stating he had worked 8.75 hours writing copy. I want to be of integrity but feel his price is outrageous.He wrote less than 12 sentences. Granted GOOD copy writing can take hours and if he had given something useable I have no problem in paying what he asked.
We had no written agreement. He knew the entire project only has $350 for copywriting, which I did and he gave a recycled tag line.
What should I do?

Thank you, 
Sonja

Comment: Even if you have no signed agreement, verbal agreements are still binding in many cases.  You will have to get professional legal advice about your circumstances.

Comment: I would just ignore the bills without any contract.

Answer (score 2):

You pay when your answers are "YES" to these questions.

1. Have you agreed to work together on this project?
2. Have you specified the work you want from him?
3. Have you agreed on terms of payment?

Again, if your answer is "yes" you have to pay him. A contract is meeting of two minds. If there was an agreement between you, then you must pay him.

You also have to consider whether you agreed to pay him for number of hours work or for the result.

I think you want positive results. This job involves expertise. Experts can do this faster and better. But that doesn't mean you have to pay less.

Judging something unoriginal is not an excuse. Everywhere, you can debate for what is original and what is not original. Take this out from the equation unless you specified that you do not want anything that sounds like "Quality Is Job #1".

You do not pay for the number of sentences. Writing 12 powerful sentences takes more thinking that writing 1200 sentences. Take this out from the equation, except when you have agreed he has to write 1200 sentences.

This is business. You do not go to a doctor, consult them, and decide not to pay them when you are not satisfied.

However, "No" answers to the questions I wrote above is a valid argument for not paying.

Comment: I think the OP is okay with paying, but feels the money being asked for is too high.  I get the impression that point #3 is the problem for them, and being a verbal agreement compounds the issue.

Comment: He said that they "met to discuss". I have met many clients to discuss their concerns, but that doesn't always fall under consulting or agreement. When he wrote that he "would not be needing" his services, my impression was that everything was still in the "proposal" stage. Unfortunately, I cannot change his questions so I asked him three questions which I believe can guide many of us.

Comment: Discussing is one thing, agreeing is another.  Was there an actual agreement of an amount?  That is not clear.  Whichever way, it sounds like it may require a lawyer given the lack of a documented contract.

Comment: Yes, given the lack of a document contract, it is his word against the freelancer's word.

Comment: 1. We did agree to work on the project. I relayed the entire amount for complete copy writing would be $350. He did not complete the job. I stopped the process realizing he did not have the skills or understanding to do the work.

Comment: Hiring an attorney would cost more than the $350. After reading what the copy writer submitted the client refuses to pay his invoice. It took me 8 hours to write the copy and I wont be compensated for that either.

Comment: So I think you've just answered your question. Pay the $350, consider it a learning experience and make sure you hire a better contractor next time.

Comment: words of wisdom, thank you to each of you for your contribution in my business growth!